# Display local timezone not GMT offset

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I'm in England during daylight savings time (known locally as BST "British Summer Time").  I want my app to display the time with a suffix identifying the BST timezone (e.g. 12:45 BST).  The code below should do this but displays the GMT offset instead:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm z"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

This displays: `12:45 GMT+1`

The reason for this is presumably because "the system" thinks that `GMT+1` is the correct abbreviation.  For example:

```
dump(TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London"))
```

prints the following:

```
▿ Optional(Europe/London (current))
  ▿ some: Europe/London (current)
    - identifier: "Europe/London"
    - kind: "current"
    ▿ abbreviation: Optional("GMT+1")
      - some: "GMT+1"
    - secondsFromGMT: 3600
    - isDaylightSavingTime: true
```

**Question:** Is there a form of timezone identifier that correctly yields "`BST`" as the correct abbreviation for British Summer Time?

Comment: Use TimeZone.current

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633173/nsdateformatter-for-bst-instead-of-gmt1.

Comment: Side note - there is no reason to set the formatter's `timeZone` if you want to use the current timezone of the device.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  That question contains the solution.